# How to handle the encode in lxml to parse html-string properly?

Tags: python, lxml

I have a [xml file](http://s.yunio.com/bmCS5h).  please download it and save it as `blog.xml`.
It is the list of my files in Google-blogger, i write some codes to parse it ,there is a something wring with lxml .

code1:

```
from stripogram import html2text
import feedparser
d = feedparser.parse('blog.xml')
for num,entry in enumerate(d.entries):
    string=entry.content[0]['value'].encode("utf-8")
    print   html2text(string)
```

It get a right result with code1.

code2:

```
import lxml.html
import feedparser
d = feedparser.parse('blog.xml')
for num,entry in enumerate(d.entries):
    string=entry.content[0]['value'] 
    myhtml=lxml.html.document_fromstring(string)
    print  myhtml.text_content()
```

It get a wrong  output with code2.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/lxml/html/__init__.py", line 532, in document_fromstring
    value = etree.fromstring(html, parser, **kw)
  File "lxml.etree.pyx", line 2754, in lxml.etree.fromstring (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:54631)
  File "parser.pxi", line 1569, in lxml.etree._parseMemoryDocument (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:82659)
 ValueError: Unicode strings with encoding declaration are not supported.
```

code3:

```
import lxml.html
import feedparser
d = feedparser.parse('blog.xml')
for num,entry in enumerate(d.entries):
    string=entry.content[0]['value'].encode("utf-8") 
    myhtml=lxml.html.document_fromstring(string)
    print  myhtml.text_content()
```

It get a wrong  output with code3.

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/lxml/html/__init__.py", line 532, in document_fromstring
    value = etree.fromstring(html, parser, **kw)
  File "lxml.etree.pyx", line 2754, in lxml.etree.fromstring (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:54631)
  File "parser.pxi", line 1578, in lxml.etree._parseMemoryDocument (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:82748)
  File "parser.pxi", line 1457, in lxml.etree._parseDoc (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:81546)
  File "parser.pxi", line 965, in lxml.etree._BaseParser._parseDoc (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:78216)
  File "parser.pxi", line 569, in lxml.etree._ParserContext._handleParseResultDoc (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:74472)
  File "parser.pxi", line 650, in lxml.etree._handleParseResult (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:75363)
  File "parser.pxi", line 599, in lxml.etree._raiseParseError (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:74827)
 lxml.etree.XMLSyntaxError: line 1395: Tag b:include invalid
```

How to handle the encode  in lxml to parse html-string properly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[There is a bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/lxml/+bug/761215) in lxml.
Check output of this code:

```
import lxml.html
import feedparser

def test():
    try:
        lxml.html.document_fromstring('')
    except Exception as e:
        print e

d = feedparser.parse('blog.xml')
e = d.entries[0].content[0]['value'].encode('utf-8')

test() # XMLSyntaxError: None

lxml.html.document_fromstring(e)
test() # XMLSyntaxError: line 1407: Tag b:include invalid
```

So the error is confusing, the real reason why your parsing fails is that you pass empty strings to document_fromstring.

Try this code:

```
import lxml.html
import feedparser
d = feedparser.parse('blog.xml')
for num,entry in enumerate(d.entries):
    string=entry.content[0]['value'].encode("utf-8") 
    if not string:
        continue
    myhtml=lxml.html.document_fromstring(string)
    print  myhtml.text_content()
```

Comment: I suspect that there *are* parse errors in the entries but that the exception is being ignored by lxml at the wrong point. Python C-API exception handling requires code to check for exceptions at certain points and if that is not done, then the exception crops up *later on* when another exception occurs that *is* handled properly. What happens if you omit the first `test` call? Does he same `XMLSyntaxError` occur?

Comment: This should certainly be reported to the LXML project in any case.

Comment: @Martijn Pieters: yes, the same error occurs, the first `test` call was only to show that `XMLSyntaxError` message changes after parsing `e`.

Comment: Thinking about it again, the error still reflects a previous error that has not been handled; this should certainly be reported to the devs.

Comment: I've found [the bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/lxml/+bug/761215) in their bug tracker.

Answer (score 4):

You could create yourself a parser, instead of using `document_fromstring`:

```
from cStringIO import StringIO
from lxml import etree

for num, entry in enumerate(d.entries):
    text = entry.content[0]['value'].encode('utf8')
    parser = etree.HTMLParser()
    tree   = etree.parse(StringIO(text), parser)
    print  ''.join(tree.xpath('.//text()'))
```

For Blogger.com Atom feed exports, this works to print the text content of the `.content[0].value` entry.

Comment: 1.add `from lxml import etree` 2. maybe it is `print  tree.text_content()` 3.but it is a wrong output:Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 5, in <module>
AttributeError: 'lxml.etree._ElementTree' object has no attribute 'text_content'

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 5, in <module>
AttributeError: 'lxml.etree._Element' object has no attribute 'text_content'
there is a problem still.

Comment: @it_is_a_literature: my apologies, indeed that method does not exist.